# Why my code not working while copy the file extension

Tags: python

Code is below

the  files in the common folder are `data.json, data.csv,1.json,2.csv`

- just copy from .json extension to json folder
- just copy from .csv extension to csv folder

```
   import os
   mypath = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\common"
   mypathjson = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\common\json"
   mypathcsv = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\common\csv"
   f = []
   for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(mypath):
       f.extend(filenames)
       break
   extension = [i.split(".")[-1] for i in f]
   if extension == 'json':
       copyfile(mypath,mypathjson)
   
   if extension == 'csv':
       copyfile(mypath,mypathcsv)
```

Comment: the files are also only that - filenames. No directory attached - you might want to concattenate them using os.path.join with  dirpath ... and you might want to do smth like `for fn in filenames. if fn.endswith("json"): .... else: .... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix the issue, depending on your copyfile function (I assume the one from shutil) you need to actually specify the filename in the destination. Also, extensions is simply a list of extensions, no filenames attached, making it kind of useless.

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

mypath = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\common"
mypathjson = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\common\json"
mypathcsv = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\common\csv"

f = []

for (_, _, fn) in os.walk(mypath):
    f.extend(fn)
    break

for each in f:
    if each.endswith(".json"):
        copyfile(each, os.path.join(mypathjson, each))
    elif each.endswith(".csv"):
        copyfile(each, os.path.join(mypathcsv, each))
```

Comment: syntax error     copyfile(each, os.path.join(mypathcsv, each)

Comment: Sorry, missed off the final ) at the end!